# DDD - Domain entity(aggreagate) with large collection of another entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, domain-driven-design

In the below scenario

```
class Group {
    ...
    Set<User> users;
    ...
}
```

where the number of users are in 6 digits, it is safe to assume that performing any operation over the collection is inefficient directly using any ORM(JPA/Hibernate in Java, may be can be worked around with ExtraLazyCollection of hibernate).

To deal with such a situation,  is it ok, that instead of representing the domain relation between the aggregate and the composed entity as a Collection, can it be represented as an operation backed by  DomainService and subsequently by repository.

```
class Group {

   User addUser(User anUser, GroupUserService aGroupUserService){ ... }
   void removeUser(User anUser, GroupUserService aGroupUserService){ ... } 
}

class GroupUserService {

   GroupRepository  groupRepository;

   User addUser(User anUser) {
       groupRepository.addUser(anUser);
   }
}

class GroupRepository {

    User addUser(User anUser) {
      //execute the query(JQL or native) to save the user 
    }
}
```

does this sound like a reasonable solution without breaking the principles of DDD, is there a optimization that is being over-looked in this case.

Comment: References to the full `User` objects isn't the only way to model it -- how about just having a list of their IDs ? This is what's recommended when `User` is an Aggregate Root.

Comment: Also, I think you should give more thought to your Aggregate design on a transactional level. A huge collection of objects will not only be inefficient, it will also cause a lot of contention in the Aggregate that owns it. Everyone who wants to edit a `User` in a given `Group` will have to initiate a transaction on that same `Group`, potentially resulting in locking problems if there are many concurrent transactions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you may be missing the concept of a `GroupMember`.

```
GroupMember member = group.addUser(user);
groupMemberRepository.add(member);
```

Now, you may say that invariants such as "you cannot have duplicate group memberships" cannot be enforced in a strongly consistent manner because there's no aggregate root that has a boundary around all memberships.

While it is true that the business rule cannot be enforced in the domain, you may simply rely on a unique constraint in the database (assuming the storage mechanism supports them).

That's a compromise we can make in order to be strongly consistent and stay practical rather than being a purist.

However, there's also another alternative, but one that will require an in-depth business analysis. We often tend to see business rules as mathematical models, but real life often cannot be modeled as such.

What are the risks and impacts of having a duplicate membership? Can this be simply identified and corrected manually? Can this rule be made eventually consistent (an automated process gets rid of duplicates)? How often could that  really occur?

I believe those are questions you need to answer and you will often realize that the business is often more flexible than you thought and that eventual consistency is often a viable solution.

Comment: In this case the Group, I think is required to maintain a Collection of GroupMember. which may end up again to be a huge collection, suppose an operation as such is to be performed on the collection, where in the cost is huge, is my above solution a valid one. (PS: Apologies for not mentioning that my question was more about the large collection that the particular Group-User domain, which was more of an example I chose)

Comment: @SomasundaramSekar "In this case the Group, I think is required to maintain a Collection of GroupMember. which may end up again to be a huge collection" I don't get what you mean... I just shown 2 ways of modeling it without having group hold onto a collection. The solution you propose is essentially the same of my first proposition, but your implementation is less aligned with DDD. You should not execute business commands against repositories.

Comment: The approach I described can be used in any kind of relationships... e.g. `ProductCategorization cat = product.categorize(someCategory); productCategorizationRepository.add(cat);` If a product could be categorized with thousands of categories then perhaps it would make sense to use this approach.

Comment: Thanks @plalx , I get it.